# Prepopulate table from 2 other tables

Tags: sql

If I have the following 2 tables with data in them:

```
APPLICATION (app_id, application_description)

ITEM(item_id, item_description)
```

I want to pre-populate another table with data:

```
ITEM_REQUEST (app_id, item_id, quantity)
```

I.e, for each row in ITEM, insert into ITEM_REQUEST table with item_id, and app_id).
So, if there were 5 distinct ITEM rows, and 3 distinct APPLICATION rows, it would result in 5x3 =15 rows in ITEM_REQUEST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
insert into ITEM_REQUEST (app_id, item_id, quantity)
select app_id, item_id, count(*)
from application, item
group by app_id, item_id
```

Comment: That's brilliant mate. I didnt know you could do that with sql. I always assumed with you wanted to collate data from two seperate tables, you needed some sort of join).